# Problems using Scanner class

Tags: java, input, keyboard

The code works for entering wife's name and age, but fails to print the names of sons, though it displays their ages properly.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Check2
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
    String wife;
    String son1;
    String son2;
    int wifeAge;
    int son1Age;
    int son2Age;

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Wife's name? ");
    wife = keyboard.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Her age? ");
    wifeAge = keyboard.nextInt();
    System.out.println();

    System.out.println("First son's name? ");
    son1 = keyboard.nextLine();
    keyboard.nextLine();
    System.out.println("His age? ");
    son1Age = keyboard.nextInt();
    System.out.println();

    System.out.println("Second son's name? ");
    son2 = keyboard.nextLine();
    keyboard.nextLine();
    System.out.println("His age? ");
    son2Age = keyboard.nextInt();
    System.out.println();

    keyboard.nextLine();

    System.out.println("My wife's name is " + wife + ". She is " +
                       wifeAge + " years old.\nOur first son is " +
                       son1 + ". He is " + son1Age + ".\nOur " +
                       "second son is " + son2 + ". He is " +
                       son2Age + ".");
    }
}
```

Comment: read this ,will solve your issue , Possible duplicate of [Scanner is skipping nextLine() after using next(), nextInt() or other nextFoo() methods](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/scanner-is-skipping-nextline-after-using-next-nextint-or-other-nextfoo)

Comment: Learn how to use a debugger and debug your program

Comment: I've provided a working example. Please up-vote the answer and click  √ to accept, if you find the solution solves the problem well for you. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have the extra `keyboard.nextLine();` in the wrong place in your code.

```
son1 = keyboard.nextLine();
keyboard.nextLine(); // you don't need this here.

son2 = keyboard.nextLine();
keyboard.nextLine(); // nor here
```

Keep the extra `keyboard.nextLine();` line after each `keyboard.nextInt();` and your program should run fine.

```
wifeAge = keyboard.nextInt();
keyboard.nextLine(); // put it here
...
son1Age = keyboard.nextInt();
keyboard.nextLine(); // and here
```

The `nextInt()` reads only an integer value and not a new line. If you need to read a new line, you will need to put the `keyboard.nextLine();` every time you read integer values from the keyboard.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Check2
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
String wife;
String son1;
String son2;
int wifeAge;
int son1Age;
int son2Age;

Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("Wife's name? ");
wife = keyboard.nextLine();
System.out.println("Her age? ");
wifeAge = keyboard.nextInt();
System.out.println();

System.out.println("First son's name? ");
keyboard.nextLine();
son1 = keyboard.nextLine();
System.out.println("His age? ");
son1Age = keyboard.nextInt();
System.out.println();

System.out.println("Second son's name? ");
keyboard.nextLine();    
son2 = keyboard.nextLine();
System.out.println("His age? ");
son2Age = keyboard.nextInt();
System.out.println();

keyboard.nextLine();

System.out.println("My wife's name is " + wife + ". She is " +
                   wifeAge + " years old.\nOur first son is " +
                   son1 + ". He is " + son1Age + ".\nOur " +
                   "second son is " + son2 + ". He is " +
                   son2Age + ".");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`nextLine()` isn't the method you want. 
You want to use `next()` instead, as shown in the following corrected and simplified code.  You don't really want to have to manage the newlines, just let the scanner treat all the input as a string of tokens separated by whitespace, and read them in sequence.  Use the `next()` method for inputting strings and `nextInt()` for inputting integers...

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Check2
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String wife;
        String son1;
        String son2;
        int wifeAge;
        int son1Age;
        int son2Age;

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Wife's name? ");
        wife = keyboard.next();
        System.out.println("Her age? ");
        wifeAge = keyboard.nextInt();
        System.out.println();

        System.out.println("First son's name? ");
        son1 = keyboard.next();
        System.out.println("His age? ");
        son1Age = keyboard.nextInt();
        System.out.println();

        System.out.println("Second son's name? ");
        son2 = keyboard.next();
        System.out.println("His age? ");
        son2Age = keyboard.nextInt();
        System.out.println();

        System.out.println("My wife's name is " + wife + ". She is " +
                   wifeAge + " years old.\nOur first son is " +
                   son1 + ". He is " + son1Age + ".\nOur " +
                   "second son is " + son2 + ". He is " +
                   son2Age + ".");
        }
   }
```